# jquery - show message when no matches found in dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/tu8tc/2/

I need to add some logic so I can show a "No products found" message when there are no matches.  For example, click on the "Other Brand" option in the jsfiddle code, that one should return no matches.

Any ideas / suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the following jsfiddle it works fine for me

http://jsfiddle.net/tu8tc/5/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tu8tc/3/

assign your selector to a jquery variable and then check `.length` on it.  If 0, do something special.